# Saving alphabet in array gets stack smashing error

Tags: c, char, ascii

This is a little simple program to save and show all the ASCII alphabet letters in an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

        int j = 0;
        char alpha[52];

        for (i=65;i<=122;i++) {
                if (i<=90 || i>=97) {
                        alpha[j] = i;
                }
                j++;
        }

        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

It gets the following error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./program.c terminated
Canceled (Created core dump)
```

What's wrong with that code?

Comment: Well, you're setting alpha[57] when it only contains 52 elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that the array `alpha` is created to be of size 52 elements but you are inserting past the end of that last element in your loop because you increment your array index variable `j` **outside** of the `if` statement. Move the `j` increment code inside your `if` block when you add an element to the array like this

```
for (i=65;i<=122;i++) 
{
    if (i<=90 || i>=97) 
    {
        alpha[j] = i;
        j++;  /* place the increment here */
    }
    /* instead of here */
}
```

This ensures that you only increment `j` when you are actually writing to the array. Failing to do this results in `j` becoming larger than 51 which is the highest index you can write to without going past the array end.

Your code as it stands allows `j` to exceed 51 and at this point the value of `i` is also in such a range that your `if` condition is satisfied - so you write to `alpha[j]` and writing past array bounds results in undefined behaviour.

If you had used a debugger this would be been obvious from the start.